# Adding Vue.js to my theme with Webpack not working

Tags: 8, javascript

I am trying adding Vue.js into my Drupal 8 theme with my Webpack setup (which I had already working).

It's all compiling fine with Webpack, without errors after my npm script `npm run build`.

---

In my `index.js` I have:

```
import './styles.css';
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

---

In my `App.vue` I have:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <HelloWorld msg="Coming Soon: Near-Earth Objects"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
      HelloWorld
    }
  }
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

---

In my `./components` folder I have `HelloWorld.vue`

First I am trying now to render my Vue component inside `header.html.twig` like

```
<hello-world></hello-world>
```

My thoughts are, by the element  in page.html.twig I can show, arrange and position all my Vue.js components where I want. Is that correct?

But why is my component not showing up?

**Update:**

I figured out. My webpack.config.js is splitting Vue into `/themes/custom/my_theme/dist/vendors~main.bundle.js`. By this setting:

```
config.optimization = {
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: "all"
      },
```

What is the purpose of this? Isn't it better to compile it all into the same file `main.bundle.js`?

Comment: I mean, menu.html.twig will output whatever you tell it to output. If you wanted to drop a script tag there and feed it an object or array, you can. I'm not sure what any module is going to provide you here.

Comment: Is the Javascript even loaded? Have you verified all of that?

Comment: @Kevin I found something. I updated my question.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend looking into the [Decoupled Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/decoupled_pages) module which can make integrating Vue.js simpler.